# cannot find permission denied opencv/lib

Tags: c++, opencv, permissions, codeblocks

I wrote a very simple program with opencv 
and I get this problem ( I'm using TDM-GCC x64 compiler)

```
cannot find c:/opencv/opencv2/build/x64/lib permission denied
```

[image: Error image]

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main (){

    Mat image =imread("An0nymOu5.jpg");
    namedWindow("image",cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    imshow("image",image);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: Well it should not be looking in the vc14 directory if you are building with gcc. If you don't have proper binaries for your compiler you probably need to build them.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a compiler error; you can try in this link to find the toolchain
[mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)

Also assure the image file is near your program file.

try this aswell.

```
Mat image;
image = imread("An0nymOu5.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```